# Instability of nonlinear mixed effects (using nlme package) in R

Tags: r, mixed-models, nonlinear-optimization, nlme, singular

I am attempting to build a `nonlinear mixed effects model` for COVID-19 data that fits a bell curve to daily case numbers from different countries (random effects being at the country level).

The data table is too large to include in the post but here is the structure of the [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe):

```
> str(dat)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   2642 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Country.Region: Factor w/ 181 levels "Afghanistan",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ date          : Date, format: "2020-03-24" "2020-03-25" "2020-03-26" "2020-03-27" ...
 $ day           : num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ total_cases   : int  74 84 94 110 110 120 170 174 237 273 ...
 $ new_cases     : int  34 10 10 16 0 10 50 4 63 36 ...
 $ total_deaths  : int  1 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 ...
 $ new_deaths    : int  0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 ...
```

Attempt to fit the model:

```
library(nlme)
dat <- readRDS("dat.rds")

# Bell curve function defined by three parameters
bellcurve.model <- function(d, mu, var, x) {
  f <- d*exp(-((x - mu)^2) / (2*var))
  return(f)
}

# NLME Model
baseModel <- nlme(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day), 
                  data = dat, 
                  fixed = list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1),
                  random = d + mu + var ~ 1|Country.Region,
                  start = list(fixed = c(1000, 20, 20)),
                  na.action = na.omit)
```

However, this is the resulting error:

> Error in nlme.formula(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day),  : 
>     Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

I have read other StackOverflow posts suggesting that certain covariates may be confounded in the model, but the only covariate I am using here to predict `new_cases` is `day`. Any advice on what this means or tips on debugging would be greatly appreciated, especially any advice on how this may be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr:  This type of modeling is sensitive to the starting values.  I detail how to successfully fix the issue.  The three main things to aid in this fix are:

- Increase maximum iteration and function calls
- Acquire informed starting values
- Potentially restrict/subset the data as countries initially added have less information available about them

Briefly in overview:

I started tinkering by just blindly changing starting values.  Changing `c(1000, 20, 20)` to `c(20000, 10, 10)` I got the model to run error/warning free as `baseModel.naive` with a `Log-likelihood: -23451.37`.  Using increased maxima for iteration and function calls and acquiring informed starting values enabled the model to improve substantially with `baseModel.bellcurve` reporting a `Log-likelihood: -20487.86`.

---

### Naively change starting values will get rid of errors

I adjusted the starting values.  Also, I showed how to increase the maximum number of functional calls and iterations and use the verbose option.  More can be found using `?nlme` and `?nlmeControl`.  In my experience, these types of models can be sensitive to starting values and maximum iterations and function calls.

```
baseModel.naive <- nlme(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day), 
                  data = dat, 
                  fixed = list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1),
                  random = d + mu + var ~ 1|Country.Region,
                  start = list(fixed = c(20000, 10, 10)),
                  na.action = na.omit,
                  control=list(maxIter=1e2, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE))
baseModel.naive
```

Output:

```
> baseModel.naive <- nlme(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day), 
+                   data = dat, 
+                   fixed = list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1),
+                   random = d + mu + var ~ 1|Country.Region,
+                   start = list(fixed = c(20000, 10, 10)),
+                   na.action = na.omit,
+                   control=list(maxIter=1e2, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE))
  0:     30455.774:  2.23045  10.6880  8.80935 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  1:     30450.763:  2.80826  11.2726  9.37889 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  2:     30449.789:  2.94771  11.5283  9.80691 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  3:     30449.150:  3.30454  11.8277  10.0329 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  4:     30448.727:  3.64209  12.2237  10.4571 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  5:     30448.540:  3.97875  12.5637  10.8217 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  6:     30448.445:  4.31754  12.9055  11.1826 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  7:     30448.397:  4.65727  13.2480  11.5420 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  8:     30448.372:  4.99746  13.5908  11.9008 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  9:     30448.360:  5.33789  13.9337  12.2591 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 10:     30448.354:  5.67844  14.2767  12.6173 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 11:     30448.351:  6.01905  14.6197  12.9753 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 12:     30448.349:  6.35969  14.9627  13.3333 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 13:     30448.349:  6.70035  15.3058  13.6913 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 14:     30448.348:  7.04102  15.6489  14.0493 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 15:     30448.348:  7.38170  15.9919  14.4073 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 16:     30448.348:  7.72237  16.3350  14.7652 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 17:     30448.348:  8.06305  16.6781  15.1232 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 18:     30448.348:  8.40373  17.0211  15.4811 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 19:     30448.348:  8.74441  17.3642  15.8391 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 20:     30448.348:  9.08508  17.7073  16.1971 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
 21:     30448.348:  9.42576  18.0503  16.5550 -11177.6  3277.46 -1877.96
  0:     30108.384:  9.42573  18.0503  16.5550 -11183.6  3279.09 -1879.43
  1:     30108.384:  9.42568  18.0503  16.5550 -11183.6  3279.09 -1879.43
  2:     30108.384:  9.42544  18.0502  16.5548 -11183.6  3279.09 -1879.43
  0:     30108.056:  9.42539  18.0502  16.5548 -11168.0  3239.13 -1879.51
  1:     30108.056:  9.42526  18.0502  16.5549 -11168.0  3239.13 -1879.51
  0:     30108.055:  9.42523  18.0502  16.5549 -11150.0  3223.70 -1879.28
  1:     30108.055:  9.42523  18.0502  16.5549 -11150.0  3223.70 -1879.28
```

```
> baseModel.naive
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day) 
  Data: dat 
  Log-likelihood: -23451.37
  Fixed: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1) 
         d         mu        var 
4290.47415   35.32178   38.44048 

Random effects:
 Formula: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1)
 Level: Country.Region
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev       Corr   
d        1.402353e-01 d    mu
mu       2.518250e-05 0      
var      1.123208e-04 0    0 
Residual 1.738523e+03        

Number of Observations: 2641
Number of Groups: 126
```

But then maybe that isn't enough.  See the `Corr` with the 0's?  Something seems off.  So I took a page from Roland ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549369/2727349) and decided to get a self starting function that was similar to your `bellcurve.model`.
I also tried subsetting the data to `Country.Region`s that have a minimum number of days in case that was an issue.  I am detailing my results/code here in sections and at the end (in the Appendix) it is all together for a quick copy and paste.

### Preliminaries & Data exploration

To explore things, I tried limiting the data to countries that had a minimum number of days.  I chose 45 days (5 countries) and slowly increased it up to 1 day (full dataset).  I used `data.table` to calculate and display pertinent things.

```
library(nlme)
library(nlraa)
library(data.table)
dat <- readRDS("dat.rds")
str(dat)
setDT(dat)


# Bell curve function defined by three parameters
bellcurve.model <- function(d, mu, var, x) {
  f <- d*exp(-((x - mu)^2) / (2*var))
  return(f)
}


dim(dat)
head(dat)

## how many countries?
dat[,uniqueN(Country.Region)]

## number of days/rows per country.region:
print(dat[,.N,by=Country.Region][order(N)], nrows=200)
dat[,N:=.N, by=Country.Region]


minimum_days <- 45
## model restricted to following countries/regions:
data.frame(Country.Region=(as.character(unique(dat[N>=minimum_days]$Country.Region))))
```

### Get automatic starting values from nls() and the data

This is where [Roland's answer in a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549369/2727349) comes into play.  We need an automated way to get informed starting values, and one way of doing that is using `nls()` and a self starting function.  You can make a self starting function out of your `bellcurve.model` but I found `SSbell` that was similar and decided to make use of it.  I run `nls()` with `SSbell` and get starting values for the `SSbell` formulation which has  `ymax` (corresponds to `d` of `bellcurve.model`) and `xc` (corresponds to `mu` in `bellcurve.model`).  For the `var` starting value in `bellcurve.model` I first calculate each and every `Country.Region`'s variance and then selected one of the smaller ones, settling on the 20%-tile because that worked for `minimum_days<-45` and `minimum_days<-1` (full data).

```
## use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549369/2727349
## but instead of SSlogis
## use nlraa::SSbell
## we can get starting values for d and mu.
plot(new_cases~day, data=dat[N>=minimum_days])
nls_starting_values <- nls(new_cases ~ SSbell(day, ymax, a, b, xc), data=dat[N>=minimum_days])
summary(nls_starting_values)

## calculate a starting value for var:  the median of Country.Region specific variances
variances <- sort(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1)
range(variances)
quantile(variances, seq(0,1,0.05))

##var.start <- median(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1, na.rm=T)
##var.start <- min(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1, na.rm=T)
var.start <- quantile(variances, 0.20)
var.start
```

Again -- I had to play around a bit -- but if you take the 20%-tile of empirical variances the `nlme` call for `bellcurve.model` the code will run for `minimum_days <- 45` as well as `minimum_days <- 1` (full dataset).  With our starting values calculated and potentially our dataset restricted, we fit two `nlme` models: one using `SSbell` and the other `bellcurve.model`.  Both will run for `minimum_days<-45` and only `bellcurve.model` will converge for `minimum_days<-1` (full dataset).  Lucky!

### Two nlme calls:  one with `SSbell`, the other for `bellcurve.model`

```
# NLME Model: using ssbell and nls_starting values for ymax, a, b, xc
baseModel.ssbell <- nlme(new_cases ~ SSbell(day, ymax, a, b, xc), 
                         data = dat[N>=minimum_days], 
                         fixed = list(ymax ~ 1, a ~ 1, b~1, xc~1),
                         random = ymax + a + b + xc ~ 1|Country.Region,
                         start = list(fixed = c(    coef(nls_starting_values) )),
                         na.action = na.omit,
                         control=list(maxIter=1e6, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE)
)
```

```
# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and nls_starting values for ymax for d;
# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and nls_starting values for xc   for mu;
# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and                    var.start for var
baseModel.bellcurve <- nlme(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day), 
                            data = dat[N>=minimum_days], 
                            fixed = list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1),
                            random = d + mu + var ~ 1|Country.Region,
                            start = list(fixed = c(coef(nls_starting_values)[c(1,4)], var.start )),
                            na.action = na.omit,
                            control=list(maxIter=1e6, 
msMaxIter = 1e6, 
msVerbose = TRUE)
)
```

### Compare the output

```
baseModel.ssbell
baseModel.bellcurve
```

Showing the output for  `minimum_days<-45` shows similar fits (look at likelihood).

```
## 5 countries DATA minimum_days <- 45
> baseModel.ssbell
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: new_cases ~ SSbell(day, ymax, a, b, xc) 
  Data: dat[N >= minimum_days] 
  Log-likelihood: -2264.706
  Fixed: list(ymax ~ 1, a ~ 1, b ~ 1, xc ~ 1) 
         ymax             a             b            xc 
 1.026599e+03 -1.164625e-02 -1.626079e-04  1.288924e+01 

Random effects:
 Formula: list(ymax ~ 1, a ~ 1, b ~ 1, xc ~ 1)
 Level: Country.Region
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev       Corr                
ymax     1.731582e+03 ymax   a      b     
a        4.467475e-06 -0.999              
b        1.016493e-04 -0.998  0.999       
xc       3.528238e+00  1.000 -0.999 -0.999
Residual 8.045770e+02                     

Number of Observations: 278
Number of Groups: 5
```

```
## 5 countries DATA minimum_days <- 45
> baseModel.bellcurve
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day) 
  Data: dat[N >= minimum_days] 
  Log-likelihood: -2267.406
  Fixed: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1) 
        d        mu       var 
965.81525  12.73549  58.22049 

Random effects:
 Formula: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1)
 Level: Country.Region
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev       Corr       
d        1.633432e+03 d     mu   
mu       2.815230e+00  1.00      
var      5.582379e-03 -0.01 -0.01
Residual 8.127932e+02            

Number of Observations: 278
Number of Groups: 5
```

Showing output for `baseModel.bellcurve` for `minimum_days<-1` (full dataset) shows an improvement from `baseModel.naive` where I blindly and arbitrarily fiddled with the starting values for the sole purpose of getting rid of the errors and warnings.

```
## FULL DATA minimum_days <- 1
> baseModel.bellcurve
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day) 
  Data: dat[N >= minimum_days] 
  Log-likelihood: -20487.86
  Fixed: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1) 
         d         mu        var 
1044.52101   25.00288   81.79004 

Random effects:
 Formula: list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1)
 Level: Country.Region
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev       Corr       
d        4.285702e+03 d     mu   
mu       5.423452e+00 0.545      
var      3.008379e-03 0.028 0.050
Residual 4.985698e+02            

Number of Observations: 2641
Number of Groups: 126
```

`Log-likelihood: -20487.86` for `baseModel.bellcurve` vs `Log-likelihood: -23451.37` for `baseModel.naive` The Corr matrix in `baseModel.bellcurve`  looks better, too.

#### Appendix: Code in one grab.

```
library(nlme)
library(nlraa)
library(data.table)
dat <- readRDS("dat.rds")
str(dat)
setDT(dat)


# Bell curve function defined by three parameters
bellcurve.model <- function(d, mu, var, x) {
  f <- d*exp(-((x - mu)^2) / (2*var))
  return(f)
}


dim(dat)
head(dat)

## how many countries?
dat[,uniqueN(Country.Region)]

## number of days/rows per country.region:
print(dat[,.N,by=Country.Region][order(N)], nrows=200)
dat[,N:=.N, by=Country.Region]


minimum_days <- 45
## model restricted to following countries/regions:
data.frame(Country.Region=(as.character(unique(dat[N>=minimum_days]$Country.Region))))



## use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/27549369/2727349
## but instead of SSlogis
## use nlraa::SSbell
## we can get starting values for d and mu.
plot(new_cases~day, data=dat[N>=minimum_days])
nls_starting_values <- nls(new_cases ~ SSbell(day, ymax, a, b, xc), data=dat[N>=minimum_days])
summary(nls_starting_values)

## calculate a starting value for var:  the median of Country.Region specific variances
variances <- sort(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1)
range(variances)
quantile(variances, seq(0,1,0.05))

##var.start <- median(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1, na.rm=T)
##var.start <- min(dat[N>=minimum_days, var(new_cases, na.rm=T), by=Country.Region]$V1, na.rm=T)
var.start <- quantile(variances, 0.20)
var.start




# NLME Model: using ssbell and nls_starting values for ymax, a, b, xc
baseModel.ssbell <- nlme(new_cases ~ SSbell(day, ymax, a, b, xc), 
                         data = dat[N>=minimum_days], 
                         fixed = list(ymax ~ 1, a ~ 1, b~1, xc~1),
                         random = ymax + a + b + xc ~ 1|Country.Region,
                         start = list(fixed = c(    coef(nls_starting_values) )),
                         na.action = na.omit,
                         control=list(maxIter=1e6, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE)
)


# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and nls_starting values for ymax for d;
# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and nls_starting values for xc   for mu;
# NLME Model: using bellcurve.model and                    var.start for var
baseModel.bellcurve <- nlme(new_cases ~ bellcurve.model(d, mu, var, x = day), 
                            data = dat[N>=minimum_days], 
                            fixed = list(d ~ 1, mu ~ 1, var ~ 1),
                            random = d + mu + var ~ 1|Country.Region,
                            start = list(fixed = c(coef(nls_starting_values)[c(1,4)], var.start )),
                            na.action = na.omit,
                            control=list(maxIter=1e6, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE)
)


baseModel.ssbell
baseModel.bellcurve
```

Comment: this is clear, detailed, and I appreciate the variety of approaches (all well-described) that you showed to illuminate the problem. You have my +50, but just going to leave this up for the rest of the bounty period in case anyone has another perspective to add.